# Creating a Sliding Indicator Under the Main Navigation when User Scrolls

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

I was wondering if it was possible to create an indicator that moved across the bottom of the main navigation as the user scrolls down the page. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ky6Vo.jpg) is an image of what I hope to make my main navigation look like.

The goal would be to have the tabbed part move as the user scrolls to different sections of the page.

Is this possible? And if so, can you point me in the direction of a tutorial or jquery plugin? 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can customize this to suit your need. http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-cool-animated-menu-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some plugin does it very well:

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

http://curtain.victorcoulon.fr/

http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrolldeck.js/

http://pagescroller.com/

Comment: Thanks Kirkas! That is definitely what I was looking for, but I decided to go into another direction anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Scrollspy in Twitter Bootstrap does this straight out of the box.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy - tells you how.

Scroll down the page and keep an eye on the left hand menu and you'll see the effect too.